# Float vs Double data type in Hive

Tags: floating-point, hive, double

As per the [Hive's documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types):

FLOAT (4-byte single precision floating point number)

DOUBLE (8-byte double precision floating point number)

What does 4-byte or 8-byte single precision floating point number mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 bytes and 8 bytes are the space they take to represent. In all likelihood, the numbers are represented in IEEE 754 [single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) format.

In short, floating-point  numbers numbers are represented as +/- d * 2<sup>e</sup>
with respectively in the single-precision case d being limited to 0 ≤ d < 2<sup>24</sup> and in the double-precision case  0 ≤ d < 2<sup>53</sup>. Note that even fractional numbers with a simple expression in decimal, like 0.1, are not automatically representable exactly in these formats. Instead 0.1 ends up represented as 13421773*2<sup>-27</sup> in single-precision, and as 3602879701896397*2<sup>-55</sup> in double-precision. These are good approximations because 2<sup>27</sup> is 134217728 and 2<sup>55</sup> is 36028797018963968. The double-precision approximation is better, and none of these is exact, because 0.1 can never be written as d * 2<sup>e</sup> for any integers d and e.